# Help to change icon in my location

Tags: android, google-maps, геолокация, иконки

Я использую этот код для отображения юзера на карте:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

На карте отображается синяя точка. Я хочу подставить свою иконку, для этого нужно определяться свои координаты, а подставлять их в **Marker**, но этом этапе у меня вываливается ишибка. Нужна ваша помощь.

```
Location location = googleMap.getMyLocation();
        LatLng target = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Marker myLoc = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(target)
                .title("ME"));
```

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MyLocation layer not enabled
    at com.google.a.a.ab.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.el.j(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.onTransact(SourceFile:281)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.getMyLocation(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getMyLocation(Unknown Source)
    at com.hrom.andrew.travelshops.Fragments.MapsFragment.onResume(MapsFragment.java:91)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1832)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Вот мой код:

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment{
    private static View view;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_maps, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
            Marker city = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CityCoordinate.KYEV)
                    .title("KYEV"));

            Location location = googleMap.getMyLocation();
            LatLng target = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            Marker myLoc = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(target)
                    .title("ME"));

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(CityCoordinate.KYEV, 13));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, этот метод уже устаревший по документации. [Вот тут можно посмотреть.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getMyLocation())
И проверьте все разрешения в манифесте.